# Get the first jquery element in a deep search and break traversal

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to force jquery `find()` to only return the first matched element and not the childs of that element. Something that would be called "nearest"...

Comment: Clarification that you are looking for a "set", "group" or "array" of elements at the first found level of traversal (based on your comments) might make the desired functionality more clearly stated.

Answer (score 1):

There is [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). The only thing with this is that it propagates up the DOM.

Comment: I would want to search for the childs not parents. Same as closest() but the other way, down, the tree. find() doesnt break when finding an child element, but continues deeper. I'd need something of a "break" option to find() to prohibit going deeper.

Comment: I think you have some acceptable answers for this above. If you know that it is only one level deep you can use `children` as it is not recursive.

Comment: I guess there is no such function and I'll need to implement it myself using children() recursively. TNX.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find the first matched element use `:first`

eg:

`<ul>`

<li>One</li>

<li>Two</li>

<li>Three</li>

</ul>

you would do:

`$('ul').find('li:first');`

or you could just use the `>` in your selector to return ONLY the children:

`$('ul > li');`

will ONLY return li's which are a direct child of the UL

using them both together:

`$('ul > li:first');`

will return the FIRST li which is a DIRECT child of the UL.

Comment: Yes, something like find(), however if the <li> s are nested it should stop with the level it first finds an entry and not traverse deeper...

Comment: No... find() will find all li's contained in the selector... it won't care how deep it will be. To get only DIRECT CHILDREN you need to use the selector parameter ">" (eg: $('ul > li') or $('div#container > div')) and then to find the FIRST DIRECT CHILD you need to use :first (eg: $('ul > li:first') or $('div#container > div:first')). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might do

```
$jqObj.find( '.dummy:eq(0)' )
```

This would return the first matched element.

Comment: Not quite. Still the function I search should return a set. Kind of an umbrella of all the first found element in every sub-branch. I'd say that would be the the equivalent to closest() but downward.